# Не генерируется код таблиц при добавлении ADO.NET Entity Data Model в проект

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем добра. Столкнулся с проблемой при создании в проекте элемента "ADO.NET Entity Data Model". При создании модели не генерируется код таблиц из модели:

[image]

Раньше всё делал точно также и работало..
P.S Первичные ключи в таблицах имеются

Comment: Переходите на Entity Framework. ADO.NET в таком формате мало кто использует, такой подход устарел.

Comment: @aepot у нас в работах (в колледже) оба этих подхода перемешаны, я пробовал устроить дело с помощью всякого рода SqlConnections и пр. но только потратил время в пустую из-за нужды работы с ListView..

Comment: "Перемешаны" это не значит ведь, что вы должны писать так, как написано "на заборе", верно? ADO.NET это низкоуровневый компонент, на основе которого сделан EF. Это как вон, лопата и экскаватор, что то копает, что это, только одно займет у вас кучу времени, а другое за пару часов решит задачу. Также и тут, в EF если по уму поступите, поймете его, ваш код будет простым `var users = db.Users.Where(x=>Age > 20); // Получить всех пользователей, которым больше 20`. К тому-же, сейчас принято использовать Миграции, это как GIT но для базы, это еще одна из причин, почему на чистом ADO не пишут.